# Treeview validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, webforms, treeview

The treeview has leaf node checkboxes.I need to validate the treeview
if atleast one of the node is checked and not more than a specfic(say 3 nodes) number of nodes  a user can select.
Note:The Treeview is a asp.net treeview(not an ajax treeview)

Answer (score 11):

Alright, since you didn't mentioned what type of validation you want, I'll do both client side and server side. My `TreeView` is named `tvTest`
First, add a `CustomValidator` to you Asp.Net page:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
  ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Note: don't set the `ControlToValidate` property.
Next, add this script (also to your Asp.Net page) for client side validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
    var treeView = document.getElementById("<%= tvTest.ClientID %>");
    var checkBoxes = treeView.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var checkedCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
        checkedCount++;
      }
    }
    if (checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < 4) {
      arguments.IsValid = true;
    } else {
      arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
  }        

</script>
```

And last, add this to your code-behind for server side validation:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
  if (tvTest.CheckedNodes.Count > 0 && tvTest.CheckedNodes.Count < 4) {
    args.IsValid = true;
  } else {
    args.IsValid = false;
  }
}
```

Of course, you'll want to change the limits for the minimum and maximum number of nodes the user can check.